# Having troubles using .eof

Tags: c++, eof

Right now im working on a program for a class, but I can't make inf.eof work.
The data file is:

```
Julie 100 100 100 100 100
Sam 90 0 100 95 90
Trudy 85 77 100 87 81
Will 85 81 0 89 72
George 81 83 100 79 55
Hannah 87 90 100 99 95
Cathy 93 96 95 82 65
Hal 65 71 0 75 88
Xena 100 100 100 100 0
```

And the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;
double score;

double getave(int a,int b)
{
        double average;
        average = 1.0 * (a + b)/2;
        return average;
}

void getclassave()
{

}

double getgrade(double score)
{
    double grade;
if(score >= 90)
    grade = 'A';
else if(score >=80)
    grade = 'B';
else if(score >= 70)
    grade = 'C';
else if(score >= 60)
    grade = 'D';
else
    grade = 'F';
return grade;
}

void printtitles()
{

}



void main()
{
ifstream inf;
    inf.open("input.data");
ofstream outf;
    outf.open("data.out");
outf.setf(ios::fixed);
outf.precision(2);
double name, qu1, qu2, prg1, prg2, fnl;
while(!inf.eof())
{   
    inf >> name >> qu1 >> qu2 >> prg1 >> prg2 >> fnl;
    cout << name << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

I'm only working on void main() right now, because I need to be able to read in the file to do the rest. I want "whine(!inf.eof())" to loop untill it reads the last line of data, and then show it worked by printing all the names on new lines in the output file. But right now it causes an infinite loop that outputs infinite lines of "-92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00" in my output file. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. `int main()` is right. If your compiler didn't warn you about `void main()`, increase its warning level. If your book told you to use `void main()`, get a better book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3):

This should work :-

```
while(inf >> name >> qu1 >> qu2 >> prg1 >> prg2 >> fnl)
{   

    cout << name << endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but now it just runs and doesn't output anything

Comment: @user2820902 because your `name` is double. Fix to use :`std::string name; double qu1, qu2, prg1, prg2, fnl;`

Comment: That fixed it. Its the same mistake i made in my last program that i overlooked in this one.

Answer (score 3):

Using `stream.eof()` to control the loop for input is almost always wrong and you'll need to know quite precisely what you are doing to use `eof()` in this context. In all cases you **always** want to check if your input was successful **after** you tried reading from a stream:

```
while (inf >> name >> qu1 >> qu2 >> prg1 >> prg2 >> fnl) {
    std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this and now it just doesn't output anything.

Comment: I guess, it would print after coming back from the [misguided] call to `std::system()`. Replace `system(pause);` by `std::cin.ignore();`: the output isn't flushed until there is a reason to flush (`std::endl` does flush but is the wrong thing to use for flushing).

Comment: @DietmarKühl OP has used `name` as double

Comment: @P0W: good point. The flushing issue and the misuse of `std::system()` still stays, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something more diagnostic friendly:

```
while (inf >> name)
{
  inf >> qu1;
  if (!inf.good())
  {
      std::cerr << "Error reading qu1.\n";
      break;
  }
  inf >> qu2;
  if (!inf.good())
  {
      std::cerr << "Error reading qu2.\n";
      break;
  }
//....
```

Yes, you *can* read all the variables in one statement, but that makes identifying where the failure was, difficult.  When reading all in one statement, you don't know which variable caused the failure.